# Why on Pesah are we more strict with Kitniyoth than we are with real grains?

Tags: halacha, minhag, passover, kitniyos-semigrain-legume

We obviously are very strict with the 5 grains on Pesah, but we do eat food made with them, namely Matzah. And with the exception of the issue of "[Gebrochts](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/7249/5)", we do allow Matzah to be re-engineered into other foods.

Yet, when it comes to [Kitniyoth](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/9103/5), it seems that we are more strict. I have never seen corn chips, for example, for Pesah (for Ashkenazim). Yet most mainstream producers of chips make a baked (not fried) variety.  I don't know anything about the potential composition or taste of such chips being ground back into meal and used for baking, but that's because I've never seen it done, either.  Would it not follow that, for Ashkenazim, Kitniyoth baked into chip form (or tortilla form or taco form) following the same procedures as for Matzah should be acceptable (and potentially re-engineerable into other foods)?

Why are we so strict in this regard?

Comment: Actually some poskim make this very point. The question is whether any poskim disagree. Popular stringencies, especially at this time of year are often baseless in halakha. This question would be improved with citations to sources prohibiting consumption of such kitniyot that would be permitted if made from the 5 grains.

Comment: @double please re-read that question. This is not a duplicate.

Comment: "Would it not follow that, for Ashkenazim, Kitniyoth baked into chip form (or tortilla form or taco form) following the same procedures as for Matzah should be acceptable (and potentially re-engineerable into other foods)?" Isn't that the same question?

Comment: @double he's asking about Matzah. I'm asking about Kitniyoth. In fact, I've revised my comment because I failed to read the full answer over there. I don't believe the answer fits the question. He's not asking about whether Matzah made from Kitniyoth is allowed qua Kitniyoth. He's asking if it is Matzah.

Comment: He's asking "Can one take rice, grind it, put water on it and bake it within 18 minutes and eat it on Pesach", or so he says in a comment

Comment: @double ok, fair. Though that should really be edited into the question, because that's not at all how I read it.

Comment: @SethJ To be fair to him the word "matza" probably doesn't mean "from 5 grains" (though we use it nearly exclusively to mean that) but something like "flat cake"

Comment: If this question is focused on the re-engineering of matzah vs. the potential re-engineering of under-18 minute crackers made from kitniyot, is it still a duplicate?

Comment: @Danno Not sure what you mean. Like Gebrokhs?

Comment: @DoubleAA the question mentions the re-engineering of matzah - grinding it up and reusing it as cake meal. If it then asks about a parallel kitniyot cracker (made in under 18 minutes) being ground up and reused as something else, would this question still be a duplicate of one which focused only on the potential for making matza out of kitniyot

Comment: I guess not. What would the concern be? Doesn't sound very interesting